# Date Conversion to UTC in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, datetime-conversion

I have the below dates received in an Excel cell. I want them to be subtracted from 8 hours from the given date

```
2022-03-16T23:02:14+08:00
2022-03-17T07:59:46+08:00
2022-03-17T08:00:34+08:00
```

Here, I need output as for Eg:

```
2022-03-16
2022-03-16
2022-03-17
```

Comment: Simply minus 8 hour from your given date time.

Comment: Where 8 hours is 1/3 of a day, so use a formula that has <date>-1/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using helper columns to explain what happens:
[image]

- Column B returns the plain date
- Column C returns the time part
- Column D adds both values and subtracts the 8 hours (calculated as a decimal of 24 hours). INT is used to only return the date part - without time part.

Comment: It worked using formula
=INT(DATEVALUE(MID(L2,1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(L2,12,8))-8/24)

Comment: Perfect - I used the helper columns to visualize the steps - but obviously you can merge all into one formula

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are stored as string in excel cells then you may use below formula-

```
=TEXT(SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</s><s>"),"T","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()<=2]"))-TIME(8,0,0),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

[image]